# WPF: How do I handle an event from a Model to dynamically update xaml in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, events, data-binding, mvvm

I've hit a bit of a dead end in trying to figure this one out... Using the MVVM pattern in WPF, our C# Model fires an event to say something has happened. I want to be able handle that event in my ViewModel and then either kick of a storyboard or change the visibility of a hidden panel on the current Xaml Page. This has to be handled with no Code Behind.

I can sync for the event in my ViewModel, update a property to say what the name of that event is and fire a NotifyPropertyChanged even but how do I get that to either kick off a storyboard or map to a boolean true/false on the Visibility property of my Grid? The property I bind to hs to be the event name as different grids may be shown based on different events so I need a way of mapping this to a boolean. However the ideal solution would be to kick off a storyboard. I've looked at DataTriggers but they all seem to be linked to styles and not to actual pages.

Any ideas of how I can achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've used this in the past to kick off a storyboard in code-behind

```
Storyboard animation = (Storyboard)this.FindResource("ShowPanelStoryboard");
animation.Begin();
```

This code goes behind the View, not in the ViewModel. Personally, I don't mind some code behind my View providing it is only related the View. In the project I used this in, I added a listener to the `VisibilityChanged` event and when it got changed to Visible, I ran the storyboard.

As for showing your popup, there's a few ways. One of my favorites was just adding an `IsPopupShown` property to the ViewModel, binding my panel's visibility to it, and setting it to true anytime the popup should be shown. The ViewModel then handles the events that trigger the popup being shown or not.

An alternative as suggested by [Dave White](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217799/wpf-how-do-i-handle-an-event-from-a-model-to-dynamically-update-xaml-in-mvvm/4217945#4217945) is to use a converter. If your value is not always true/false then you could create a converter that checks if a bound value is equal to the ConverterParameter, and return a Visibility value.

Comment: Thanks Rachel - only problem I have here is I have no code behind at all. I'm working purely with Loose Xaml :( I'll maybe have a look down the Convertor route to see if this will work. Thanks for the response. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, it seems to me like what you may want to do is expose an `Event` property of type `object` in your view model.  When the view model receives an event, it sets `Event` to an object of a type appropriate for that event.  In your XAML, you have this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Event}"/>
```

and in the resource dictionary define a `DataTemplate` for each specific type of event you want to display.  If `Event` is null, nothing gets displayed.  If `Event` contains an object that you've defined a `DataTemplate` for, it gets displayed using that template.

Yes, you'll need to create a class for each type of event (if you don't already have one).

Another way is to implement the poor man's template selector:

```
<TextBlock Text="This is displayed if Foo contains 'BAR'">
   <TextBlock.Style>
      <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
         <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Property="Foo" Value="BAR">
               <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
<TextBlock Text="This is displayed if Foo contains 'BAZ'">
   <TextBlock.Style>
      <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
         <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Property="Foo" Value="BAZ">
               <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

It's kind of stupidly verbose, but it's an easy way to handling a lot of mutually-exclusive display options.

Comment: Thanks Robert - this sounds totally doable. I'll work through the example to see if does the trick. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Bind the Visibility property on your grid, in Xaml, to the boolean property on your ViewModel.

```
<Grid Visibility="{Binding Path=VisiblePropertyOnViewModel}">
```

Now do whatever you need in your ViewModel and set the property. As long as it does INotifyPropertyChanged or is a DependencyProperty, it will work.

I'd have to do more digging to figure out how to kick off a Storyboard, but I have no doubt it would be almost as easy. Storyboards can be kicked off by PropertyTriggers as well I believe. I'll leave this to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dave - really appreciate it! Problem is this property is not a bool. It's a string. Basically there's a whole bunch of events that can occur (hundreds actually!) so I'm thinking more on the lines of loosely typing this and letting the Xaml do some sort of: -

<Grid Visibility="{Binding Path=EventReceieved == "Event1"}">

so the expression evaluates to true and this sets the Visibility to true...

Comment: Visibility has 3 possible values, you will need a converter to bind it to a boolean and choose what true/false means for Collapsed/Hidden/Visible.

Comment: Cheers Matthieu - I was hoping to avoid a convertor since I've have an endless unbounded list of events. I guess Convertors have to be used if you want to do any Expression Evaluation?

Comment: @Slippy - Remember, your ViewModel can handle all of the events in whatever manner is required, and THEN set a Xaml-based Visibility property that is bound to the ViewModel to a property of type Visibility enumeration. If you are binding your View to the ViewModel properties, you do not need to bind your view to events fired by the model.

Comment: Thanks Dave - yea I was initially thinking the same. But... how would I identify that particular event? If I have circa 100 events in the system is there any way to avoid writing circa 100 Visibility properties that I would have to bind to? If eventA occurs I would show GridA, if EventB occurs, display GridB and so on...

Comment: @Slippy - You're ViewModel listens to ~100 events, and figures out what it has to do. Then you set one property that controls visibility on your ViewModel, and that property is bound to the appropriate control in the XAML.  Do not just hook up ~100 events to your XAML. If you have ~100 events that each controls the visibility of something on your display, there are more elegants ways within your ViewModel and the MVVM pattern to configure what needs to be shown.